# How to use read_line_to_codes & atom_codes iteratively to generate array of lines as strings of my .txt file?

Tags: prolog, gnu-prolog

I am trying to use `read_line_to_codes(Stream,Result)` and `atom_codes(String,Result)`. These two predicates first, read line from file as an array of char codes, and then convert this array back to string. Then I would like to input all those strings to an array of Strings.

I tried the recursive approach but have trouble with how to actually instantiate the array to empty in the beginning, and what would be the terminating condition of `process_the_stream/2`.

```
/*The code which doesn't work.. but the idea is obvious.*/

process_the_stream(Stream,end_of_file):-!.
process_the_stream(Stream,ResultArray):-
        read_line_to_codes(Stream,CodeLine),
        atom_codes(LineAsString,CodeLine),
        append_to_end_of_list(LineAsString,ResultArray,TempList),
        process_the_stream(Stream,TempList).
```

I expect a recursive approach to get array of lines as strings.

Comment: Generally, people asking to do this kind of thing are under the impression the next step (processing a big list of strings, parsing them perhaps) will be easy, but often it is easier to recast the _whole_ parsing problem using [tag:dcg]s instead.

Comment: @DanielLyons ... and sometimes you just need a list of lines as strings. It depends.

Comment: I literally need a list of strings. I solved this problem in 2 other languages in the same way, now trying to do it in prolog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follows a Logtalk-based **portable** solution that you can use as-is with most Prolog compilers, including GNU Prolog, or adapt to your own code:

```
---- processor.lgt ----
:- object(processor).

    :- public(read_file_to_lines/2).

    :- uses(reader, [line_to_codes/2]).

    read_file_to_lines(File, Lines) :-
        open(File, read, Stream),
        line_to_codes(Stream, Codes),
        read_file_to_lines(Codes, Stream, Lines).

    read_file_to_lines(end_of_file, Stream, []) :-
        !,
        close(Stream).
    read_file_to_lines(Codes, Stream, [Line| Lines]) :-
        atom_codes(Line, Codes),
        line_to_codes(Stream, NextCodes),
        read_file_to_lines(NextCodes, Stream, Lines).

:- end_object.
-----------------------
```

Sample file for testing:

```
------ file.txt -------
abc def ghi
jlk mno pqr
-----------------------
```

Simple test:

```
$ gplgt
...

| ?- {library(reader_loader), processor}.
...

| ?- processor::read_file_to_lines('file.txt', Lines).

Lines = ['abc def ghi','jlk mno pqr']

yes
```

Answer (score 0):

I sense a lot of confusion in this question.

- The question is tagged "gnu-prolog" but `read_line_to_codes/2` is not in its standard library.
- You talk about strings: what do you mean? Can you show which one of [the type testing predicates in GNU-Prolog](http://www.gprolog.org/manual/gprolog.html#sec71), or maybe [in SWI-Prolog](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=typetest) should succeed on those "strings"?
- You *expect* a recursive approach. What does that mean? You want a recursive approach, you must use a recursive approach, or you think that if you did it you would end up with a recursive approach?

To do it in SWI-Prolog without recursion, and get *strings*:

```
read_string(Stream, _, Str), split_string(Str, "\n", "\n", Lines)
```

If you need something else you need to explain better what it is.