# How to trim right whitespaces from String in prolog?

Tags: prolog, whitespace, trim

I would like to trim right whitespace from strings for example.
"Dog   " becomes "Dog" , "          " becomes "".
How could this be achieved?

I know SWI prolog has trim whitespace predicate however it trims String from right and left.

However I am also using GNU prolog so looking to write my own solution.

Comment: As a follow-on to [yesterday's question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55365567/how-to-use-read-line-to-codes-atom-codes-iteratively-to-generate-array-of-line), let me reiterate that it would be a good idea to investigate [tag:dcg]s and try solving your problem holistically in a new way, rather than getting frustrated trying to convert your Python or whatever directly to Prolog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert a string into a list of characters (see [convert string to list in prolog](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18224717/535275)), write a predicate to manipulate it however you want, and then convert the resulting list back to a string.

Comment: Alternatively, [`:- set_prolog_flag(double_quotes, chars).`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8269897/772868)  In this manner it is true that `"abc" = [a,b,c].`

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to accomplish this using a DCG in SWI-Prolog.  I know you said you're using GNU Prolog, but maybe this will at least be helpful for others using SWI-Prolog:

```
:- use_module(library(dcg/basics)).

trimmed(S) --> blanks, string(S), blanks, eos, !.

trim(S, T) :-
  string_codes(S, C), phrase(trimmed(D), C), string_codes(T, D).
```

Answer (score 0):

GNU Prolog is one of the supported [Logtalk](https://logtalk.org) backend compilers. With it, you gain access to (portable) libraries (and developer tools!) that allows you to easily solve the problem. For example, if your strings are represented using atoms, you can use the [`atom::replace_sub_atom/4`](https://logtalk.org/library/atom_0.html#replace-sub-atom-4) predicate:

```
| ?- {types(loader)}.
...
yes

| ?- atom::replace_sub_atom(' ', '', 'Dog ', Output).          

Output = 'Dog'

yes
| ?- atom::replace_sub_atom(' ', '', ' becomes ', Output).

Output = becomes
```

If instead you're using double-quoted terms, their meaning depends on the `double_quotes` flag value, In this case, you can use the [`list::subtract/3`](https://logtalk.org/library/listp_0.html#subtract-3) predicate. For example:

```
| ?- current_prolog_flag(double_quotes, Value).

Value = codes

yes

yes
| ?- list::subtract("Dog ", " ", Output).

Output = [68,111,103]

yes
| ?- list::subtract(" becomes ", " ", Output).

Output = [98,101,99,111,109,101,115]

yes

| ?- set_prolog_flag(double_quotes, chars).

yes
| ?- list::subtract("Dog ", " ", Output).

Output = ['D',o,g]

yes
| ?- list::subtract(" becomes ", " ", Output).

Output = [b,e,c,o,m,e,s]

yes

| ?- set_prolog_flag(double_quotes, atom).    

yes
| ?- atom::replace_sub_atom(" ", "", "Dog ", Output).

Output = 'Dog'

yes
| ?- atom::replace_sub_atom(" ", "", " becomes ", Output).

Output = becomes

yes
```